# SQL syntax error for deleting multiple rows from a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-delete

I have a relational MySQL database using InnoDB which connects courses to course attendees. The problem with this database is that the `course_id` column in `course_attendees` was not set as foreign key. There are alot of courses missing where the `course_attendees` table is trying to refer to.

I wanted to delete those records, since the courses don't belong anymore. I wrote this select query which selects all the courses that should be deleted:

```
SELECT
    ca.`id`
  FROM `course_attendees` AS ca
    LEFT JOIN `courses` c
      ON ca.`course_id` = c.`id`
  WHERE c.`id` IS NULL
```

Now, when I try to wrap this in a DELETE query with the use of a subquery like this:

```
DELETE FROM courses AS C1
WHERE C1.`id` IN (
  SELECT
    ca.`id`
  FROM `course_attendees` AS ca
    LEFT JOIN `courses` c
      ON ca.`course_id` = c.`id`
  WHERE c.`id` IS NULL
);
```

I get the following error:

```
[2018-08-30 08:34:26] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS C1

[2018-08-30 08:34:26] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS C1
[2018-08-30 08:34:26] WHERE C1.`id` IN (
[2018-08-30 08:34:26] SELECT
[2018-08-30 08:34:26] ca.`id`
[2018-08-30 08:34:26] FROM `course_attendees` AS c' at line 1
```

Since the SELECT query works, what is the problem here and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

After Tim's answer, it got me into this error:

```
[HY000][1093] You can't specify target table 'courses' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer delete query is not correlated to the subquery at all, so you don't logically need aliases:

```
DELETE
FROM courses
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM
    (
        SELECT ca.id
        FROM course_attendees AS ca
        LEFT JOIN courses c
            ON ca.course_id = c.id
        WHERE c.id IS NULL
    ) t
);
```

I'm not sure that aliases are allowed in a delete statement on just a single table.  They are allowed for a delete join, but you're not doing that.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. It got me into this error though `[HY000][1093] You can't specify target table 'courses' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: This still seems like more query than is strictly necessary

Comment: Wrap one extra time with a subquery to fix that problem.

Comment: @Strawberry I give up trying to write an delete inner join, if you can then I'm happy to upvote you.  It's more complicated than it looks.

Comment: It worked because we fixed the alias problem, and then wrapped the subquery.  This forces MySQL to materialize that set of course attendee `id` values, so the delete won't complain about it.